# `AttributeError`when trying to concatenate two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm importing the below database and am trying to create a new column named "street" that concatenating one numerical column and one string column. However I'm getting the "AttributeError". The database looks like this:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
path_to_data = "C:\\Users\\BI Dashboard\\"
data_file_name = 'Flint_Water_Residential_Testing_revised.csv'
dat = pd.read_csv(path_to_data + data_file_name, encoding= "ISO-8859-1")

dat.rename(columns={'Sample Number':'sample_number','Date Submitted':'date_submitted','Analysis (Lead)':'lead_analysis',
        'Lead (ppb)':'lead_ppb','Analysis (Copper)':'copper_analysis', 'Copper (ppb)':'copper_ppb',
        'Street #':'street_number', 'Street Name':'street_name','City':'city','Zip Code':'zip_code'}, inplace=True)

dat['sample_number'].fillna(' ', inplace=True)
dat['street_number'].fillna(' ', inplace=True)
dat['street_name'].fillna(' ', inplace=True)
dat['city'].fillna('FLINT', inplace=True)
dat['zip_code'].fillna(' ', inplace=True)
dat['state'] = 'MI'

dat['street'] = dat['street_number'].str.cat(dat['street_name'], sep=' ')
```

The error code that I got from the last line of my code says:

[image]

I guess it's trying to complain that "street_number" column is not a string. Can someone please tell me how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try `astype(str)` like this `dat['street'] = dat['street_number'].astype(str).cat(dat['street_name'], sep=' ')`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `street_number` column is integer type. You need to convert it to string. You can do that with [`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
dat['street'] = dat['street_number'].astype(str).str.cat(dat['street_name'], sep=' ')
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! One additional question, what if my code is: `dat['address'] = dat['state'].str.cat(dat['zip_code'], sep=' ')` which means it's a string + int. Do I need to convert anything?

Comment: @vivi11130704 I just checked and a conversion is required. I would do `dat['zip_code'].astype(str)` once again.

Comment: Otherwise, you get a `TypeError`.

Comment: I see. So what does this .str do (the .str before the .cat) ?

Comment: @vivi11130704 That allows you to access the string methods associated with that series. Exclude the `.str` and you get `AttributeError: Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype`. That's pretty indicative, it means those string methods are bound to the accessor attribute `str`.

Comment: oh I see. Thanks for your kindly help!!